# Ошибок нет, но данная сортировка не функционирует

Tags: c++

```
class StudenR
{
    string Name;
    int NumGroup; 
    string Sex;
    int Marks[5];
    int AVM;
public:
    StudenR();
    StudenR(ifstream &fin);
    bool Read(ifstream &fin);
    void Write(ofstream &fout);
    int AvMark();
    void SetMarks(int &marks);
    int GetMarks(int i) { return Marks[i]; }
    int GetAvMark() {return AVM;}
    ~StudenR();
};
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StudenR.h"

using namespace std;


StudenR::StudenR()
{
    Name = "<unknown>";
    NumGroup = 0;
    Sex = 'x';
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Marks[i] = 0;

}
StudenR::StudenR(ifstream &fin) {
    fin >> Name;
    fin >> NumGroup;
    fin >> Sex;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fin >> Marks[i]; 
            AVM = AvMark();
    }
}
bool StudenR::Read(ifstream &fin) {
    if (!(fin >> Name))return false;
    if (!(fin >> NumGroup))return false;
    if (!(fin >> Sex))return false;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (!(fin >> Marks[i]))return false;
    return true;

}
int StudenR::AvMark() {
    int AvMark = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        AvMark += Marks[i];

    }
    AvMark /= 5;
    return AvMark;

}
void StudenR::SetMarks(int &marks) {
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        this->Marks[i] = marks;
}

void StudenR::Write(ofstream &fout) {
    fout << Name << " " << NumGroup << " " << Sex << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fout << Marks[i] << " ";
    }
    fout << endl;
}
StudenR::~StudenR()
{
}
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StudenR.h"
using namespace std;

void Read1(StudenR*students, ifstream &fin, int &n);
void Write(StudenR*students, ofstream &fout, int n);
void WriteAvM(ofstream&fout, StudenR*students, int n);
void Sort(StudenR*&studets, int n);
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("Text.txt");
    ofstream fout("res.txt");

    StudenR *students = new StudenR[100];

    int n = 0;
    Read1(students, fin, n);
    Write(students, fout, n);
    fout << endl << endl << endl;

    WriteAvM(fout, students, n);
    fout << endl << endl << endl;
    Sort(students, n);
    Write(students, fout, n);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    delete[]students;
    return 0;
}

void Read1(StudenR *students, ifstream &fin, int &n) {
    n = 0;
    for (; !fin.eof(); n++) {
        if (!students[n].Read(fin))return;
    }
}
void Write(StudenR *students, ofstream &fout, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        students[i].Write(fout);
}


void WriteAvM(ofstream &fout, StudenR *students, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        students[i].Write(fout);
        int AvMark = students[i].AvMark();
        fout << "AvMark" << i + 1 << "=" << AvMark << endl;
    }
}
void Sort(StudenR*&students, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (students[j].GetAvMark()<students[j + 1].GetAvMark()) {

                StudenR s = students[j];
                students[j] = students[j + 1];
                students[j + 1] = s;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Это похоже на пузырьковую сортировку, однако вложенный цикл должен начинаться не с 0 каждый раз, а с `i`, так как ведущий элемент уже самый меньший.

Comment: почему  i < n - 1,  и   j < n - 1 - i   ?...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно написать так:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j < n - i; ++j) {
                if (students[j].GetAvMark()<students[j + 1].GetAvMark())
                //...
```

Так вы сортируете по убиванию, а если хотите сортировать по возрастанию, то поменяйте знак сравнения

Comment: Сама функция никак не сортирует

Comment: Ну вот, я и написал что нужно менять, а вы сравните с тем, что вы написали

Comment: все равно не сортирует

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что не сортирует?  Берите любой массив целых и вместо  students[j].GetAvMark()   вставляйте элемент этого массива. Если массив сортируется, тогда  проверьте  возвращает ли желаемое число GetAvMark() ?..  Я не знаю что вы пытались делать.  Может в вашем файле нет соответствующих данных для получения    fin >> Marks[i];

Comment: В файле вывода осуществляется только средняя оценка, но не сортируется по убыванию средней оценки.